# Who exactly is this stranger here?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

Before Aquaman, Bruce Wayne speaks to Iceland chief:

> Bruce Wayne: There are enemies coming from far away. I need warriors.
> This **stranger**, others like him. I'm building an alliance to defend
> ourselves.

Who exactly is this stranger here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is indeed talking about Aquaman here.

> I'm asking for your help.
> I believe there's a stranger, comes to this village from the sea.
> He comes in the winter when the people are hungry... and brings fish.

....

> Well, this stranger... Doesn't come by ship.
> There are enemies coming, from far away. I need warriors. I'm building an alliance, to defend ourselves.

He's talking to Arthur Curry at the time, discussing Aquaman as if it were someone else, this local legend, but he indicates at the end of the dialogue that he was aware of who he was talking to from the beginning.

> Can you at least point me to Atlantis?
>
> Arthur Curry. Also known as Protector of the Oceans. The Aquaman. I hear you can talk to fish.

### The scene where Bruce meets Aquaman and asks for his help

Admittedly, that clip is not from the Synder cut, but as far as I can tell, the meaning doesn't change here.